# system print dialog box in C# mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery

Chrome have it's own print dialog.
I wants to show system print dialog box without using like :

```
<script>

window.print();

</script>
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. What you have there will open a print dialog box and is (as far as I know) the only way to open a print dialog using JavaScript. I don't see how this question relates to C#.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.print(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: actually chrome have it's own print dialog it's override the system print dialog if user press ctrl shift p then the system dialog appears,